# In Rstudio ,change the setting value of Graphics , the export image function show error

Tags: r, rstudio

In Rstudio, after change the setting value ('Tools->GloablOptions->General->Graphics->GraphicsDevice Backend:') from '(default)' to 'AGG', the Rstudio 'Export' function show below Error ?
Anyone can help ?

Chang the setting to 'default', the error will disappear. But the 'AGG' make the plot borders more smooth/clear.

[image]

Comment: What version of R and RStudio are you using?

Comment: RStudio and R verson : Version 1.4.1717  /  R version 4.0.5

Comment: Have you tried `install.packages("ragg")` and re-running?

Comment: @Allan Cameron ,  after  install pacakge 'ragg' ,it's ok now .Thanks for your help!